# Using single credit card to enroll more than one Apple ID into Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, developer-program

I am an Apple Developer enrolled into paid Apple Developer program. I wish to create a new Apple ID and enroll it separately into Developer Program.

Can I use the same credit card to make payment for enrolling that I used with my first account? Can I use this approach to further enroll more Apple IDs?

Ccan I receive money from these accounts into one credit card?

Comment: I see no reason why not.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Maybe it violates the rules of the apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use one card to pay for several Apple developer accounts. A credit card number isn't locked to a single Apple developer account.

The payments made by Apple to developers in-lieu of the sale on App Store/iTunes Store/iBooks Store is not made as credit into the credit card, but in the bank account that's provided when enrolling into Developer Program. From [iTunes Connect FAQs](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/books/faq/Payments%20and%20Financial%20Reports_Getting%20Paid):

> Payments are made within 45 days of the last day of the month in which app purchases were made. To receive payment, you must have provided all required banking and tax information and documentation, as well as meeting the minimum payment threshold.

Comment: I paid for one developer account. After several times, my account was blocked due to violation of one application (not for all apps). If I register a new account with card and upload apps from the first account without violation. Everything gonna be alright? I have no problem with uploading or something else?

Comment: @user making payment using the existing card for the new account shouldn't be a problem. However, what could likely create a problem is uploading app(s) from one account into another.

Comment: Why uploading can create a problem? Because I uploading apps without violations. These apps was banned because only one of apps have violations. Not for all apps. How can I prove it in apple? Can there be any way to explain this?

Comment: You can not freely (as in free will) move published apps between accounts (even the ones that you own). Your new account may get flagged. If you are unsure about an action and can not locate any supporting document providing resolution for your problem, it's best to get in touch [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com//contact/)

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean by - "Your new account may get flagged". For example: I had an apple developer account. After several time my account was blocked. Now I want to register new account on same name. And upload new another app (which was not in the app store and in previous account). At what time my apple developer account may be flagged? After register on same card or after review (if in review I will have problem)?

Comment: @user What was the reason that caused your old account to get blocked? Do you have any account under your name currently active, serving apps (free or paid) on the App Store?

Comment: In my application, part of the name violates some Apple rules. Now I do not have an active account for this card and name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82986/discussion-between-nimesh-neema-and-user).

Comment: _Hello. Could you help me with my question please?_ - I have several different accounts enrolled in Developer Program. Can I get Apple's payments from two different accounts to the same bank account (debit card) each month? Will my developer accounts be blocked? Is this a violation of the rules? Also link https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352755/get-a-payment-to-same-bank-account?noredirect=1#comment464387_352755

Comment: @NimeshNeema Can I upload same Apps with some modification in two different Account? They will not find out that this is same App, right? (Lets say I have chat App both have same feature but UI is different, and I am sharing same device for testing but using my friend Apple account to upload new App)

Comment: @SurendraKumar Not advisable to do that. The App Store review team has means to curb such practises, and this can lead your app to be removed from the sale.